# parsing of an unknown XML, getting node names without XPATH

Tags: php, xml

I work on simple XML parser using simplified SQL. 
I have something like this

```
`<catalog>
    <library><room id="1">
    <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book></room>
   <room id="2">
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book></room>
   </library>`
```

And I need to get this:

```
`<Books><book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
  </book><book id="bk102">
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
  an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
  of the world.</description>
```

`

I don't really know what to do...Can you give me advice please? **I mustn't use xpath**.

Comment: So you can use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [SAX](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php). Google for some examples, try it yourself and if you have problems with your code, then back here and ask.

Comment: trust me, I have spent a lot of time on this. Can you recommend me something...? If not necessary i wouldn't ask here....

Comment: When I first time used SAX, [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch12_05.htm) page was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You first of all open the document you want to process the elements from:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->loadXML($buffer);
```

Then you create a new document to which you add the element to:

```
$books = new DOMDocument();
$books->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$books->formatOutput = true;
$books->loadXML('<Books/>');
```

Then you import the `<book>` element-nodes from the first document into the second and then you append them to the document-element:

```
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('book') as $book) {
    $book = $books->importNode($book, true);
    $books->documentElement->appendChild($book);
}
```

You then can reload the document for formatting purposes and output it:

```
$books->loadXML($books->saveXML());
$books->save('php://output');
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Books>
  <book id="bk101">
    <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>44.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
    <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
      with XML.</description>
  </book>
  <book id="bk102">
    <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
    <title>Midnight Rain</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
    <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
      of the world.</description>
  </book>
</Books>
```